# Java Spark broadcast and join two RDDs

Tags: apache-spark, join, rdd, broadcast

I have one large table `JavaPairRDD<String, MySchema> RDD1`, and a smaller `JavaPairRDD<String, Double> RDD2`. I want to join these two RDDs, I know the best way is to make `RDD2` a broadcast variable and then join to reduce shuffling. How to handle the broadcasting part? I mean after broadcasting, I will get a variable (A List, or Set), which is no more an RDD. How to join a broadcast variable with a RDD?

```
// I ignored the parsing part, just simplified it as loading from the files. 
JavaPairRDD<String, MySchema> RDD1 = sc.textFile ("path_to_small_dataset");
JavaPairRDD<String, Double> RDD2 = sc.textFile("path_to_large_dataset"); 

// Broadcast RDD2
Set<Tuple2<String, Double>> set2 = new HashSet<>();
set2.addAll(RDD2.collect());

// now I have set2 and RDD1, how can I join them?
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you have two RDDs which you want to join, the first one is small enough to fit into the memory of each worker (**smallRDD**), and the second one does not need to be shuffled at all (**largeRDD**).

Before joining, you have to Make sure to transform the large RDD[T] to an RDD[(key, T)]. The key represents the columns used during the join operation.

This code should do the trick in Scala (but the basic principle is the same in Java)

```
val smallLookup = sc.broadcast(smallRDD.collect.toMap)
largeRDD.flatMap { case(key, value) =>
  smallLookup.value.get(key).map { otherValue =>
  (key, (value, otherValue))
 }
}
```

I hope it helps